# Implementation of Maven version POJO in Java

Tags: java, maven

*"Version"* a common notion in software, which helps to unique states of software development. I implemented a simple POJO for *"version"* in Java. I would like to have your review about this code. I'd like to have a Java class satisfying the following requirements:

1. **Composition.** A version is composed by 3 parts: major, minor, and patch. All of them are required attributes.
2. **Digits.** Each part must be an integer. Negative numbers are NOT allowed: a valid part value should be either 0 or positive number.
3. **Incrementation.** Incrementing a version means incrementing the value of major, minor, or patch.
4. **Comparability.** Versions are comparable. Such comparison should be numeral, and should not be lexicographical. For example, `0.0.10` is greater than `0.0.9`.
5. **Serialization.** A version object in Java should be able to serialize into a string representation. And a string representation can also be deserialized into a Java object.
6. **Reversibility.** The serialization and deserialization of this object should be reversible. So an object should obtain its owner value after { serialization, deserialization }. So leading zeros are denied:

   1. Good: `"0.0.1"` -> `v(0.0.1)` -> `"0.0.1"`
   2. Bad: `"0.0.01"` -> `v(0.0.1)` -> `"0.0.1"` (not the same)
7. **Immutability.** A version object should never be changed once its instantiated. (I don't know what would be the benefits, but I feel it's a good idea).

And here's my implementation:

```
package io.mincongh.maven;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author Mincong Huang
 */
public class Version implements Comparable<Version> {

  private final int major;

  private final int minor;

  private final int patch;

  /**
   * A version contains 3 groups of digits, separated by char '.'.
   * Each group of digits should be a positive integer, without
   * leading zeros.
   */
  private static final Pattern PATTERN =
      Pattern.compile("(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\.(0|[1-9]\\d*)");

  private Version(int major, int minor, int patch) {
    if (major < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative major version: " + major);
    }
    if (minor < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative minor version: " + minor);
    }
    if (patch < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative patch version: " + patch);
    }
    if (major == 0 && minor == 0 && patch == 0) {
      String msg = "At least one argument should be non-zero among major, minor, and patch.";
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }
    this.major = major;
    this.minor = minor;
    this.patch = patch;
  }

  public static Version of(int major, int minor, int patch) {
    return new Version(major, minor, patch);
  }

  public static Version parse(String version) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(version);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse version: " + version);
    }
    int M = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int p = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    return new Version(M, m, p);
  }

  public Version nextMajor() {
    return new Version(major + 1, minor, patch);
  }

  public Version nextMinor() {
    return new Version(major, minor + 1, patch);
  }

  public Version nextPatch() {
    return new Version(major, minor, patch + 1);
  }

  public int getMajor() {
    return major;
  }

  public int getMinor() {
    return minor;
  }

  public int getPatch() {
    return patch;
  }

  public boolean isBefore(Version that) {
    return this.compareTo(that) < 0;
  }

  public boolean isAfter(Version that) {
    return this.compareTo(that) > 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Version)) {
      return false;
    }

    Version version = (Version) o;

    if (major != version.major) {
      return false;
    }
    if (minor != version.minor) {
      return false;
    }
    return patch == version.patch;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = major;
    result = 31 * result + minor;
    result = 31 * result + patch;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Version that) {
    if (this.major != that.major) {
      return this.major - that.major;
    }
    if (this.minor != that.minor) {
      return this.minor - that.minor;
    }
    if (this.patch != that.patch) {
      return this.patch - that.patch;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return major + "." + minor + "." + patch;
  }

}
```

Example usages:

```
// Create a new version
Version a = Version.of(1, 0, 0);
Version b = Version.of(1, 0, 1);

// Compare
a.isBefore(b);
a.isAfter(b);

// Next versions
Version M = a.nextMajor();
Version m = a.nextMinor();
Version p = a.nextPatch();
```

What do you think about this implementation? Your review is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Did you know that in Maven versions, there's also the possibility of using a classifier, like `1.2.3-mystuff-SNAPSHOT` ? I suppose you're happy without the classifiers?

Comment: What are you planning to use this class for?

Comment: This is just an exercise. I didn't know that there's a classifier, it would be better to include it and the SNAPSHOT. Is it possible to have timestamp too? Ideally, this class can handle the use cases of Maven.

Comment: As far as I know, timestamp is only included for SNAPSHOTs after you build a SNAPSHOT, I wouldn't say that they're a part of the version, unless you consider already built jars. So, maybe the right answer is both yes and no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very readable, well-formatted, very clear. Well done.

You have implemented hashCode and equals well and all other methods look well-implemented.

It's good that you define the `Pattern` only once. Your exceptions are clear and well-implemented.

If I have to complain about something, it would be these variable names:

```
int M = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
int m = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
int p = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
```

They could be `major`, `minor`, `patch` or `parsedMajor` etc.

One thing that you might want to think about is the implementation of `nextMajor()` and `nextMinor()`. Let's say that you have a version `1.2.3` and you bump the major version, does the next version then become `2.2.3`? In your code, yes, but in reality that becomes `2.0.0`. So your `nextMajor` should return `new Version(major + 1, 0, 0)` and `nextMinor` should return `1.3.0`, so `new Version(major, minor + 1, 0)`.

Besides this, again: Very well done!

For fun, I'd recommend that you implement support for classifier versions, like `1.2.3-mystuff-SNAPSHOT`, otherwise I'd say you're ready for more complicated challenges because this one was apparently way too easy for you.

Comment: I didn't think about the problem of next versions. That's very important! And I'll try to implement the notion of classifier and snapshot, too. Thanks for your advice, Simon!